# .htaccess rewrite a subdomain with a variable

Tags: .htaccess, variables, url-rewriting

Is this possible point a subdomain to specific variable?

http://whatever.example.com point to http://example.com/file.php?var=1

http://whatever1.example.com point to http://example.com/file.php?var=2

Tried the recommended answer below - the code work but no css style:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?whatever\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ /file.php?var=1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?whatever1\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ /file.php?var=2 [L,QSA]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?([^.]+)\.example\.com$

RewriteRule ^ /file.php?var=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Got it working by adding `<base href=""/>`in header and making a folder called cssfolder for my css because root folder wasn't working. I dont know why?

```
<base href="../" /> "not working"

<base href="/" /> "not working"

<base href="./" /> "not working"

<base href="/cssfolder/" /> "this work"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure that is possible. But you need to tell a few things apart:

The actual host name in the URL ("subdomain") is *not* part of the path a `RewriteRule`s pattern is internally matched against. You need to use a `RewriteCond` to access that information:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?whatever\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ /file.php?var=1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?whatever1\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ /file.php?var=2 [L,QSA]
```

A typical variant would be to hand over an actual name instead of a numeric value. Here the GET variable would become `v=whatever` or `v=whatever1`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?([^.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ /file.php?var=%1 [L,QSA]
```

This assumes that all hosts/subdomains are served from by same http server, of course, since it is an *internal* rewrite.

In general I would recommend that you take a look at the documentation of the tools you want to use. That documentation is, as typical for OpenSource software, of excellent quality and comes with great examples: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: tried this but css style doesnt load

Comment: @Mel That may well be the case. Most likely because your css files cannot be requested from `/file.php?var=...`. That is an aspect you never mentioned in your question through which is why it is impossible to consider it in an answer.

Comment: if i type type this to address bar example.com/file.php?var=1234 , my css work

Comment: Could it be that you are looking at cached css content? Check your browsers networking console, always test with a fresh anonymous browser windows.

Comment: You will certainly receive help with that issue. But for that you need to describe the issue. We cannot somehow _guess_ that. What are the actual references to that css content? And what is the internal resource that should get mapped to? What response do you actually get from the http server when requesting that css and you have above rules implemented?

Comment: i got it working. thanks to you. i wasn't able to get the css working thru root folder with uour .htaccess. check my edit post above. do you know why wasn't working thru root folder

Comment: I think you want to read a bit about the difference between _relative_ and _absolute_ paths and how paths are interpreted by the apache http server. Why things did not work without that additional header is something I still cannot say since you still did not provide additional information about your actual issue. Anyway, great to hear that you managed to find a working setup. Have fun!